# AudioKit did not start

Tags: swift, audio, audio-recording, audiokit

I'm a Chinese developer,so my English is not good,I have met some trouble with AudioKit when the setting of play background in Appdelegate,
I write some code to play audio background :

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //设置音频后台播放
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }catch{

    }
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()//设置后台波播放
    return true
}
}
```

then a homeViewController is the rootViewController,it can push recordViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var toRecordButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "首页"
}
@IBAction func toRecordAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = RecorderViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

next is the code of recordViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKitUI
import SnapKit
import MediaPlayer
class RecorderViewController: UIViewController {
private var fileForm = ".m4a"
private lazy var inputPlot:AKNodeOutputPlot = {
    let plot = AKNodeOutputPlot.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 150))
    return plot
}()
var micMixer: AKMixer!
var recorder: AKNodeRecorder!
var player: AKAudioPlayer!//播放背景音乐的播放器
var testPlayer:AKPlayer!//试听的播放器
var tape: AKAudioFile!
var micBooster: AKBooster!
var moogLadder: AKMoogLadder!
var delay: AKDelay!
var mainMixer: AKMixer!
let mic = AKMicrophone()//麦克风对象
fileprivate var micTracker:AKMicrophoneTracker?//话筒输入追踪器
fileprivate var playerTracker:AKAmplitudeTracker?//其他的追踪器

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.title = "录音"
    self.setupViews()
    self.stetupConfigs()
}
private func setupViews(){
    self.view.addSubview(inputPlot)
    let button = UIButton.init()
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.center.equalTo(self.view.snp.center)
        make.size.equalTo(CGSize.init(width: 80, height: 50))
    }
    button.setTitle("开始录音", for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("停止录音", for: .selected)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .selected)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
private func stetupConfigs(){
    // Clean tempFiles !
    AKAudioFile.cleanTempDirectory()

    // Session settings
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium

    do {
        try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
    } catch {
        AKLog("Could not set session category.")
    }

    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

    // Patching
    inputPlot.node = mic
    micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)

    // Will set the level of microphone monitoring
    micBooster.gain = 0
    recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)
    if let file = recorder.audioFile {
        testPlayer = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
    }
    testPlayer.isLooping = true


    moogLadder = AKMoogLadder(testPlayer)

    mainMixer = AKMixer(moogLadder, micBooster)

    AudioKit.output = mainMixer
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
    }
     micBooster.gain = 0
}
@objc private func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton){
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected == true {
        do {
            try recorder.record()
        } catch { print("Errored recording.") }
    }else{
        recorder.stop()
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

when these code run,it print this:

```
2018-03-20 14:37:34.101644+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568244] 
[DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
AKMicrophone.swift:init():45:Mixer inputs 8
2018-03-20 14:37:50.045692+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568082] [aurioc] 
918: failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non- 
inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)
AKAudioFile.swift:deleteFileWithFileName:139:"334A33E7-1237-447A-8A6A- 
AA5F57CA5871.caf" deleted.
AKAudioFile.swift:cleanTempDirectory():157:1 files deleted
2018-03-20 14:37:50.482190+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568082] [mcmx] 338: 
input bus 0 sample rate is 0
2018-03-20 14:37:50.482772+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568082] [avae] 
AVAEInternal.h:103:_AVAE_CheckNoErr: 
[AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1266:Initialize: (err = 
AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph, 
kOutputChainOptimizedTraversal, *GetOutputNode(), 
isOutputChainActive)): error -10875
2018-03-20 14:37:50.482822+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568082] [avae] 
AVAudioEngine.mm:149:-[AVAudioEngine prepare]: Engine@0x1038b0460: 
could not initialize, error = -10875
2018-03-20 14:37:50.572746+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568082] [mcmx] 338: 
input bus 0 sample rate is 0
2018-03-20 14:37:50.572815+0800 RecorderTest[18970:5568082] [avae] 
AVAEInternal.h:103:_AVAE_CheckNoErr: 
[AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1266:Initialize: (err = 
AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInOutputChain(ThisGraph, 
kOutputChainOptimizedTraversal, *GetOutputNode(), 
isOutputChainActive)): error -10875
RecorderViewController.swift:stetupConfigs():90:AudioKit did not start!
```